# Bad inputs for unit testing on a text parser

Tags: .net, unit-testing, parameters

I would like to write the unit test for a text parser class but I am not sure about the **Bad Inputs** I need to give to the test method in order to be sure it work in all possible cases.

The method uses some regular expression plus string manipulation, but if I understood well the **Unit Testing approach** I don't have to concentrate on the method implementation but see it as a **black box**. Right?

The method is

```
Public Function GetSymbol(ByVal symbol As String) As SymbolInfo
```

if the symbol specified is found it return an instance of SymbolInfo will all needed data, otherwise it return Nothing.

My problem now is creating the range of **bad inputs** for this method, but they are so many that I have no idea how to do it in an effective way.

Can you give me some hints? I am newbie about unit testing, just started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that a pure Black Box approach is completely right.

My thinking would go like this:

A). Look at the inputs. Think of ways that a person could send in bad stuff. Examples:

- Null reference
- Empty string
- Very long string
- String with all digits
- String with weird punctuation characters
- String with unprintable, or strange character sets

In each case you need to know the expected outcome - that is the formal definition of what is "right". To this extent you are doing Black Box testing. You don't want to know what the code does, you want to know what it should do.

B). But now we open the box. You look at the code and look for the various branches it has. Do your tests exercise those branches? There are coverage tools to analyse your tests. Suppose that you had a special case: to take a silly example, the word MY-SPECIAL-SYMBOL is subject to some special processing, there's an "If" for that. Your test case needs to include that as an input. You often can only find such corner cases by looking at the code. (Yes the spec should tell you, but the implementors often find interesting extras, so look at the code.

C). What about side effects? Suppose that this method was supposed to update a cache for each symbol it found. It's a formal requriement of the component, and yet the interface doesn't tell you that. Again you are going inside the Black Box. So here you might use mocks to let you verify that the component in turn passed the right data to the cache api.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will try your approach. Do you think that if the Public Method returns a complex object is it a good idea to create the test for internal methods that create that object?

Comment: If they are private methods (and presumbly they would be) then you can't explicitly test them. Instead you need to devise your tests of the public interface to exercise the different paths in those private methods. This is where code coverage tools can  be useful in identifying paths that have not been tested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET you could use [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) to generate inputs for your unit tests. Even if you don't keep the generated tests themselves it would give you a good set of inputs to get you started.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know Pex as soon as I have some time I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, you can start with all values that are clearly outside of the accepted range, like `Nothing` or `null`, the empty string, strings with whitespace chars, strings with seperator chars. If all those bad inputs are handled gracefully or raise the appropriate exception you can start building bad input with the knowledge of what good input is. Like both upper- and lowercase versions of the input strings, strings including international characters, etc. What is an optimal set of bad inputs depends heavilly on the structure of what you parse.